# Why is the speed of Console.WriteLine more inconsistent than Debug.WriteLine?

Tags: .net, vb.net, console.writeline

This code outputs almost all 0's with an occasional output of 3-5.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 1000
    Dim Watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    Debug.WriteLine(Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds & " - Processing Time1")
    Debug.WriteLine(Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds & " - Processing Time2")
Next
```

This code outputs almost all 0's with an occasional output of 200.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 1000
    Dim Watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    Console.WriteLine(Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds & " - Processing Time1")
    Console.WriteLine(Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds & " - Processing Time2")
Next
```

Any ideas why?

The only difference is Console.WriteLine. Also, it seems having two WriteLines per loop is important for some reason.

I found this out while trying to time my code speed and got seemingly random 150ms spikes during a loop.

Comment: The real question is why do you care? As for why there's a difference, `Console.WriteLine` always writes to the console. `Debug.WriteLine` writes to any configured debug listeners. Nothing will be written if there are no listeners. Don't use `Console.WriteLine` for debug messages. Use a proper logging library and ensure you only log what you need to log

Comment: BTW your measurements are wrong and `ElapsedMilliseconds` probably returns the exact same value each time unless the OS schedules some other thread to run. Writing to the console or debug listeners takes nanoseconds or microseconds, not milliseconds. If you want to measure anything you'd have create the stopwatch *outside* the loop, use a lot more iterations, use *ticks* instead of milliseconds (ie the Elapsed or ElapsedTickes properties) and once finished, calculate the overall time.

Comment: Or better yet, use BenchmarkDotNet and let it measure each case properly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok ill use ticks for simple tests and I will look into BenchmarkDotNet. Thanks. I was actually trying to figure out why some individual loops took longer and that's why I didn't average the times together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily for us Microsoft has released the source code of the .NET platform [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

A quick inspection shows that Debug.Writeline uses the Writeline method of the TraceInternal class. You can see an example [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Debug.cs,217) and the TraceInternal method [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/TraceInternal.cs,457)

As you can see there are a lot of stuff going on involving hooked TraceListeners, locks etc. So we can assume that Debug.WriteLine should be slower in general but only if there are any "extra" TraceListeners configured and of course other IDE parameters that in some way interfere with the Debug infrastructure.

The [Console.WriteLine](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,2082) method uses the [TextWriter.WriteLine](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,452) method which is designed to be fast (at least as fast as possible, take a look at their comments).

About the inconsistency that you ask it isn't easy to answer (and IMO you should not try to answer) because of three reasons:

1. When you are developing in a high level language or platform like
   .NET then you should not bother of how much time the "internals"
   take because you can not have any control on them. I mean that you
   cannot make the WriteLine methods faster unless you write your own
   "faster" versions but that beats the purpose of using a high level
   platform anyway. I hope you can see my point here.
2. When you are using some methods (like WriteLine) in order to output
   the time some other code of yours took to execute then you should
   not bother how much time the output method takes to complete as long
   as the result is accurate. If for example the WriteLine takes 2 seconds to show you that the code you are measuring took 1ms to complete then the 1ms is what matters even though you waited 2 seconds to find it out. If the output method is too slow then you should change your measuring method, in your case, for example, it might be faster to have a counter variable in your loop and display (WriteLine) the result at the end of it.
3. When you are developing software intended to run in multi tasking
   systems like windows you should not expect that the same code will
   always take the same time to execute every time simply because there
   are a ton of other (outside your app) parameters that can (and will)
   affect the overall performance of the system. That's why (and I am sure that you already know it) we have the restart option in a very easy to access place (LOL).

Nevertheless to finalize my answer the inconsistency of your timings depends on many factors that makes it worthless to find out why it happens. However, in your code I noticed that you are using the statement:

```
Dim Watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
```

inside the loop which is a bad thing to do because as you can see in the Stopwatch code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,77) it creates a new instance every time which is a time consuming operation. I believe that if you have it outside of the loop like:

```
Dim Watch As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
For i As Integer = 1 To 1000
    Debug.WriteLine(Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds & " - Processing Time1")
    Debug.WriteLine(Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds & " - Processing Time2")
Next
```

You will get more "consistent" results but I haven't test it though. Moreover it might be wiser to use higher timing resolution like

```
Watch.ElapsedTicks
```

because it will give you more accurate results and because if you look at the source code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,124) ElapsedMilliseconds uses a slightly different version (maybe slower) of ElapsedTicks to calculate the milliseconds.

Hope this helps.